# How to use RegEdit utility to see Virtual Registry for a Win32 UWP app

Tags: uwp, registry, desktop-bridge, regedit

Is it possible to see the Virtual Registry of my Win32 UWP app (desktop-bridge converted)? I know that all programmatic access goes to the virtual registry and that works. But I want to view it with RegEdit. Any solutions?

I remember viewing it about a year back but don't remember the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. We built a free tool called [Hover that allows you to launch an external process in the context of your MSIX/APPX container](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/registry-in-msix-container-hover.html). Using this tool you can launch Regedit, cmd.exe, PowerShell, or other processes inside your container, and thus have access to the same resources your app does.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `regedit.exe` in the context of a UWP app. The regedit.exe spawned this was will show you the same registry view as visible to the app.

**Step 1**: Get App ID, and Family name of the package

```
PS > $pkg=Get-AppxPackage -Name "*package_name*"
PS > $familyName=$pkg.PackageFamilyName
PS > $id=(Get-AppxPackageManifest $pkg).package.applications.application.id
PS > $params = @{
    AppId             = "$($id)"
    PackageFamilyName = "$($familyName)"
    Command           = 'regedit.exe'
}
```

**Step 2**: Wrap these params into a hashmap and pass it to `Invoke-CommandInDesktopPackage`. This command should be run in an **elevated** powershell prompt.

```
PS > $params = @{
     AppId             = "$($id)"
     PackageFamilyName = "$($familyName)"
     Command           = 'regedit.exe'
 }
PS > Invoke-CommandInDesktopPackage @params
```

The regedit.exe window which now opens will have registry keys from the UWP app's context.

[image: regedit.exe running in context of a UWP app]

Answer (score -1):

Based on the document, App packages contain a `registry.dat file`, which serves as the logical equivalent of HKLM\Software in the real registry. But there is no clear explanation about where it is stored. And all writes under HKCU are copy-on-written to a private per-user, per-app location.  For more information here: [Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#registry)

So currently, there is no good way to check that.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. But similar to Program FIles\WindowsApps folder, I recall using some other folder where I could then see the virtual Appdata and registry files for the app. It was a long time ago. To rephrase the question, is it possible to locate the virtual appdata folder being used by a particular app?

Comment: Yes, you can locate that folder under this path "**%localappdata%\packages\PublisherName.AppName_hash.**"  - more details here: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/appdata-msi-msix-appv.html